# How to read 36 v 10 Ah Li-Ion battery voltage and current(percentage)

Tags: arduino, lithium-ion, esp32, soc

How to read **36 V 10 Ah** Li-ion battery voltage and current(percentage) with **ESP32**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, about which you haven't shared a lot, the integrated ADC of the ESP32 might be appropriate for both tasks.

You can use a voltage divider of an appropriate ratio to get a voltage that's proportional to the battery voltage and within the ADC's range.

For current measurements you can use a shunt resistor in series with your load and measure the voltage across that resistor with the ADC.